# Mapping column from one dataframe to the column of a different one and replacing it with values?

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe

I try to solve the following problem:
I have these two dataframes, `df1`:

| label | term |
| --- | --- |
| A01.12 | "Culture de légumes, de melons, de racines et de tubercules" |
| A01.14 | Culture de la canne à sucre |

and `df2`:

| company | organization_activity |
| --- | --- |
| coca-cola | "Culture de légumes, de melons, de racines et de tubercules" |
| rum-factory | Culture de la canne à sucre |

I now would like to map the "term" of `df1` to the "organization_activity" of `df2` and create a new column with the name "codes" in `df2` with the respective label in `df1`.

The resulting dataframe should look like this:

| organization_activity | codes |
| --- | --- |
| "Culture de légumes, de melons, de racines et de tubercules" | A01.12 |
| Culture de la canne à sucre | A01.14 |

This partially works by using:

```
df2['codes'] = df2['organization_activity'].map(df1.set_index('term')['label'].to_dict())
```

Oddly the new column is created and filled but for a lot of terms the mapping does not work and a `Nan` value is inserted even though the "organization_activity" I am mapping exists in the "term" column. Does anyone have an idea on why this could happen? The formatting for the values in "term" and "organization_activity" is equal and there doesn't seem to be a difference in the format of values that are mappable and ones that are not. Is there maybe a different way to do this?
The dataframe I showed is just an abstract so there are multiple companies that can have the same "organization_activity".

Comment: All I could think of is maybe there some extra white spaces in one of the columns and that is why it is not matching, maybe try to trim those first ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, that is what you call a merge. Assuming you have the following dataframes:

```py
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Label': ['A01.12', 'A01.14'],
                    'term': ['Culture de légumes, de melons, de racines et de tubercules',
                             'Culture de la canne à sucre']})


df2 = pd.DataFrame({'organization_activity': [
                    'Culture de légumes, de melons, de racines et de tubercules',
                    'Culture de la canne à sucre']})

>>> df1
    Label                                               term
0  A01.12  Culture de légumes, de melons, de racines et d...
1  A01.14                        Culture de la canne à sucre

>>> df2
                               organization_activity
0  Culture de légumes, de melons, de racines et d...
1                        Culture de la canne à sucre
```

This is what a merge would give you after some cleaning:

```py
>>> df3 = df2.merge(df1, left_on="organization_activity", right_on="term")
>>> df3.drop("term", axis=1).rename(columns={"Label": "Code"})
                               organization_activity    Code
0  Culture de légumes, de melons, de racines et d...  A01.12
1                        Culture de la canne à sucre  A01.14
```

I also assume that there are some more columns in `df2`, too, which should also correctly be mapped to `Labels`/`Codes` with a merge.

Comment: Thank you! I solved it now like this: ```pd.merge(df2[["organization_activity"]], df, left_on="organization_activity", right_on="term", how="left")```